# Good virtualization solution on Ubuntu server 11.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization

I want to virtualize several linux servers on one physical machine running Ubuntu Server 11.10 for development, are there any free solutions?

Comment: -1 because the question is very vague. Nothing about what you need this for is described. I'd say you're lucky that someone even tried to answer you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KVM, Xen and VirtualBox provide you full virtualization.

LXC (Linux Containers) would be a more light solution, being similar to FreeBSD jails or Solaris zones.

All mentioned are free and open source, but since your question was very short and lacks details, I won't type a longer answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options available on vmware website. Some of them are free. Others are not.